# Conflicting meanings for "犬も歩けば" expression?

Tags: words, usage, expressions, definitions, proverbs

The expression 犬も歩けば棒に当たる (Inu mo arukeba bou ni ataru [lit. "even a dog will run into a stick if goes walking"]) is given [two definitions on jisho.org](https://jisho.org/search/inumoarukeba), both of which seem to be at odds.

1. bad things happen to those who attempt things
2. good luck may come unexpectedly​

(1.) seems to lead to "trying things is bad", and (2.) seems to lead to "try things and you might get lucky", which are basically opposite sentiments. So which interpretation is more accurate? Or if both interpretations are valid, which is more common?

For what it's worth, when I encountered it, it was translated as "every dog has their day", similar to (2.).

Answer (score 4):

Both are 'correct' interpretations. It depends on what 棒にあたる means. If interpreted as *beaten by sticks*, the phrase means (1) and if as *stumble upon (just) something*, it means (2).

According to [Wikipedia/犬も歩けば棒に当たる](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%8A%AC%E3%82%82%E6%AD%A9%E3%81%91%E3%81%B0%E6%A3%92%E3%81%AB%E5%BD%93%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8B) (quoting JapanKnowledge), the usage of (1) dates to 1758 and that of (2) to 1705.

This is purely a personal impression, but I guess (2) is more common. Also, it is not necessarily a *good luck* but more like *something*. So the overall sense is like *if you come out, you'll find something*.